# regex windows server 2012 .htaccess convert to iis

Tags: regex, windows, .htaccess, iis

i need to convert a .htaccess regex to windows server 2012 iis.
i am using parallel plesk.
i want to add a rule of this but i can not i tried too much
here some screen shots what i did 
http://prntscr.com/3pnqzk
here is the result 
http://prntscr.com/3pns3e

this is one line of old .htaccess
can anybody describe me how to add a rule of this

```
RewriteRule ^oyunu-indir$ index.php?nereye=indir [L,NC]
```

here some screen shots

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a forward slash to the rewrite path:

```
RewriteRule ^oyunu-dir$ /index.php?nereye=indir [L,R=301]
```

Without including it you'll likely end up with a 500 server error.